# Difference in PHP timestamp and mysql timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am really upset with the script I made, in which I did comparison of timestamps.
I can see that the timestamps are totally different.

1. For 2012-10-02 03:06:21, timestamp is: 1349190381
2. For 2012-10-02 04:00:50, timestamp is: 1349150450

I can't understand why the second one timestamp is lower than the first, even if the time is bigger. How can I compare two dates?

I am getting these values by strtotime() function.

**Clarification**: I am using

```
$current_timestamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$till_date_timestamp = strtotime($database_object->till_date);
```

Comment: It would be good to see the code you have used to generate these timestamps.

Comment: Is the MySQL server on the same server? May be a timezone and/or difference in time between two machines causing this.

Comment: Have you tried just comparing `time()` with `strtotime($dbobj->till_date)` ? Still wouldn't cater for timezone differences between PHP and MySQL though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the [result](http://codepad.org/7LLW9iie) that i got. They differ from what you mentioned in the question.

Code:

```
    echo strtotime('2012-10-02 03:06:21'); //outputs: 1349147181
    echo "\n";
    echo strtotime('2012-10-02 04:00:50'); //outputs: 1349150450
```

Edit:

`$till_date_timestamp = strtotime($database_object->till_date);` make sure that `$database_object->till_date` is a string.

Answer (score 2):

You sure you did it right?

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1349190381), from_unixtime(1349150450);
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1349190381) | from_unixtime(1349150450) |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| 2012-10-02 09:06:21       | 2012-10-01 22:00:50       |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

php > echo date('r', 1349190381), "\n", date('r', 1349150450);
Tue, 02 Oct 2012 10:06:21 -0500
Mon, 01 Oct 2012 23:00:50 -0500
```

what string did you use in your strtotime calls? The function **CAN** mis-interpret inputs and should not be trusted on anything but well-formed and unambiguous date strings.

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on `strtotime`! Also it's obvious that the timezone of PHP is different then the timezone of the database. Make sure the timezones are the same or get current/till timestamp like this (so that they are from one source):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS 'Current' UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datefield`) AS 'Till' FROM `table`
```